# copying html files to .docx file using docx4j

Tags: java, docx4j

I am copying multiple `HTML` files into one single `docx` files.
I see it copying but when I open the target file I see contents of only the first file out of all those `HTML` files. But the target file size is large.

This is my code below:

System.out.println(XmlUtils.marshaltoString(wordMLPackage
            .getMainDocumentPart().getJaxbElement(), true, true));

```
AlternativeFormatInputPart afiPart = new AlternativeFormatInputPart(new PartName("/hw.html") ); 
afiPart.setBinaryData(xhtml.getBytes());
afiPart.setContentType(new ContentType("text/html"));
Relationship altChunkRel = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(afiPart);
// .. the bit in document body
CTAltChunk ac = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createCTAltChunk();
ac.setId(altChunkRel.getId() );
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(ac);

// .. content type
wordMLPackage.getContentTypeManager().addDefaultContentType("html", "text/html");
wordMLPackage.save(actualFile);
```

Thanksin advance!

Comment: That code only shows adding a single AlternativeFormatInputPart?

Comment: Note: AlternativeFormatInputPart relies on Word to convert the XHTML content unless you invoke: convertAltChunks()

Comment: String xhtml in the code has all the files contents.that is, multiple html file contents.

Comment: I have added convertAltChunks() code.Even then i see only contents of first file in the target document

Comment: You can't put the multiple html file contents in a single AlternativeFormatInputPart.  You need one well formed (X)HTML file per AFIP!  Alternatively, you could programmatically merge them (ie all into a single <body>) then use a single AFIP.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked after making all the html files to a single file.

Comment: your code worked for me .